# JAX-WS Header Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-security, jax-ws

i've made a webservice where i expose some methods:

/Orders
/Plans

etc.

I would like to add authentication for every method. I would like to pass this information on HEADER request.

So, for every request i will send my username/password and the webservice will reply me with the information that i've request (if my username/password is correct), 405 or else if i cant access to this.

I would like to implement a mechanism like Parse.com.

In this webservice (reading the doc) for every rerquest i send API KEY and CLIENT KEY. I would like to do the same in my RESTful Web Service. I will access it from iPhone/Android application, but this isnt a problem.

The problem is... how secure all my methods ?

Answer (score 1):

SSL, with a filter to check for the existence and validity of the keys.